# OSB Production Logs Mixing up - Work Manger

Tags: weblogic, production-environment, workmanagers

We are using custom loggers through Java code in OSB. It was working fine till before Production environment. In production under heavy load, all application logs are getting mixed up. I need to Configure Work Manager (WM) for each application. For an OSB project, I have configured for Proxy service one WM and for multiple Business Services One WM setting max Thread Constraint to 7 [Done multiple trial and error for Max Thread]. But still under heavy loads logs are getting mixed up. What values should I actually set for Work Manager properties?

Comment: If you have a concurrency issue with you custom logger,  workmanagers won't help i'm afraid. You should review your logger implementation or configuration.

Comment: I am actually  using java.util.logging.  Under heavy load i.e different application running at same time, some Log entries are being written into the respective applications log file itself, but some are being written into wrong/other applications output file . Is there some changes I have to do to Java Code?